# Set notation OCaml

Tags: ocaml

this is just a question regarding notation in OCaml.

I am trying to test the function

```
let rec add (x : 'a) (l : 'a set) : bool =
  begin 
    match l with
    | [] -> []
    | hd :: rest -> 
      if x = hd then rest 
      else (hd :: (add x rest))
  end
```

my test case is

```
let test () : bool =
add (3 [1; 2; 4]) = [1; 2; 3; 4]
;; run_test "add 3 [1; 2; 4]" test
```

I am getting an "this expression is not a function, cannot be applied" error

Is something wrong with my notation?

Comment: The error comes from `(3 [1; 2; 4])`, where you are applying `3` to `[1; 2; 4]`. In context, you probably meant to apply function `add` to arguments `3` and `[1; 2; 4]`. You can do this with the notation `add 3 [1; 2; 4]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml doesn't have a built-in set type (instead there is a Set module, or library). So, there's also no built-in notation for set constants.

For smallish sets, one often uses lists. And, in fact, `List.mem` is a function that operates on lists (not sets). The notation for a list is like this: `[1; 2; 3; 4]`.

(As a side comment, your function named `add` doesn't add anything. But maybe you're just getting started.)

Comment: Thanks! I actually edited my post, I have made a mistake in my function. Now I am getting another error, even though I changed it. What is it referring to?

Comment: Function arguments in OCaml aren't parenthesized. To call `add` you want: `add 3 [1; 2; 4]`. I see some other problems, but one thing at a time!

Comment: I changed my add function. I think there may be something wrong with the recursive part, but I'm not quite sure what it is.

Comment: Actually the recursion looks OK to me. But other stuff is wrong. Think about (a) when element is already in the set (b) return type of function (c) how to tell if two sets are equal.

Comment: how is this any different from an insertion sort?

Comment: If you choose to keep your set as a sorted list, no difference. If you just need to test membership and insert values, you don't need to keep sorted. If you have strong requirements and lots of elements, use a real set (as gasche suggests).

Answer (score 2):

There is no set notation in OCaml. I don't know what your `'a set` type is, I don't understand why membership would be tested with `List.mem`, but it should have no specific notation.

There is a [Set.Make](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.Make.html) functor in the standard library, to be instantiated by a module having at least a type and a comparison function on keys ([see here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual004.html#htoc15)):

```
module StringSet = Set.Make(String)
let set = StringSet.(add 0 (add 1 (add 2 empty)))
let test = StringSet.mem 3 set
```

If you want a convenient notation, your best bet is to use a conversion function from lists to sets, and use the list notation:

```
let set_of_list li = List.fold_left (fun s v -> StringSet.add v s) StringSet.empty li
let set = set_of_list [0; 1; 2]
```